# Why won't my html table center on the page in IE 11?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, sharepoint-2010

I'm building a web page in Sharepoint 2010, and the code below centers successfully when I use Chrome 58 as my browser but not when I use IE 11. I have tried using text-align: center; but that didn't seem to work either. The table aligned to the left of the page when I did that. Any ideas how I can get this to center on the page in IE? Also, why does Chrome only accept "-webkit-center" instead of "center"?

```
<style>
.s4-wpcell-plain{
text-align: -webkit-center !important;
}
</style>



<table style="width:100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2" valign="top" class="s4-wpcell-plain">

<!-- content -->

</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the -webkit- from your style.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.s4-wpcell-plain{
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table style="width:100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2" valign="top" class="s4-wpcell-plain">
        fihfiehoipepfi
<!-- content -->

</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

this works perfectly on both IE and chrome. 
However, if there are styles that are specific to chrome which you want to implement, write all the required versions of it. one should be the normal and the others with the webkit or moz depending on the browser.

like

```
<style>
.s4-wpcell-plain{
text-align: -webkit-center;
text-align: center
}
</style>
```

Comment: I tried to use "text-align: center" but for some reason that will not center anything in either IE or Chrome. And "text-align: -webkit-center" will center it in Chrome but not IE. Any idea why?

Comment: Don't know, it worked fine for me. Why don't you try using the last suggestion I gave.

Comment: If none of it works, I suggest you use bootstrap. Inside a row, make 3 div. The div in the center should have just enough columns allocated to hold data , the other two divs can be used to center this div